# Redis driver with phpfastcache bundle

Tags: symfony, redis, phpfastcache

I am going to use [phpfastcache-bundle](https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache-bundle) with symfony3. I have found a documentation how to use it with file driver. But docs are poor on other drivers. How can I setup a redis driver with symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being late,

Wiki has a [page](https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache/wiki/%5BV4%CB%96%5D-The-driver-options) for all options to drivers. You can find options for redis in **Host/Authenticating options**.

The config for the drivers on the symfony bundle are exactly the same than the library, except that they are yaml-formatted. So, if you want to setup redis:

```
php_fast_cache:
    drivers:
        redis:
            type: Redis
            parameters: ~
```

Here parameters are by default but you can change it using options from pointed section in wiki.

In case parameters in wiki are not actual you can find all options in vendor folder - `vendor\phpfastcache\phpfastcache\src\phpFastCache\Drivers\Redis\Driver.php#driverConnect`.

Comment: Your link routes to homepage. Looks like it does not have wiki.

Comment: Mybad, I fixed the link, everything that is related to options and/or configuration is centralized in the main repository not the bundle repository.

Comment: may I rewrite you answer? I would like to accept it but it looks like comment not an answer.